# One-to-One? or One-to-Zero-or-One?

Tags: normalization, erd

Scenario: I am being asked to create an HR training tracker for employees of a business. in this database I am using two tables:

```
EMPLOYEE(EMPLID, LastName, FirstName, PrimaryEmail) with EMPLID as the PK, and
```

```
SUPERVISOR(SupEMPLID) with SupEMPLID as the FK/PK.
```

[image]
Every instance of SUPERVISOR relates to *one and only one* instance of EMPLOYEE (because every supervisor is an employee of the company), but not every instance of EMPLOYEE exists as an instance of SUPERVISOR (because not every employee is a supervisor).

I initially defined the relationship between EMPLOYEE and SUPERVISOR as one-to-zero-or-one [1:0,1], because again, each EMPLOYEE relates to zero or one instances of SUPERVISOR. My professor claims it is a one-to-one relationship.

Who is right here?

-------------------------------------------------[Update 1]-------------------------------------------------

1. Removed SUPERVISOR entity.
2. Created One to One-or-Many relationship between EMPLOYEE and POSITION.

[image]

[[LINK TO CURRENT LUCIDCHART]](https://lucid.app/lucidchart/2310d4d5-1b7b-4d71-8af7-b8f6eb2e0cbe/edit?viewport_loc=-2380%2C-507%2C1664%2C799%2CUqT7QdG%7EO4AL&invitationId=inv_653b49c4-1e95-4a50-97a4-c65b445ec6d2)

Comment: There is no "supervisor" entity - a supervisor is an `Employee` who has subordinates.  This is usually modeled as a self-referencing relationship (with a single top employee as their own supervisor).  In your diagram, if you're going to go with the "position" route, it would be a property of the `Position`, not the `Employee` and you'd have to take care to ensure no `Employee` has two positons.

Comment: according to the excel file i was given, every `EMPLOYEE` reports to one other person. No `EMPLOYEE` reports to no one. The two top positions are the President, and the Dir. Planning & Ops, and both report to one another. I felt a recursive relationship would be insufficient here. Yet, the relationship is still recursive in a way.

Comment: also yes, no employees in this db will have more than one position. Does this change anything? i still believe my diagram is correct based on these assumptions.

Comment: 1. Your diagram is lacking the keys to enforce that requirement.  2. Having two employees manage each other is going to cause problems - recursive relationships need to remain acyclic otherwise you'll have all sorts of problems trying to query things like "who is the top supervisor for Employee X" and getting a the top 2 officers until the maximum number of loops is reached.

Comment: I am purely going off the data i was provided and adhering to their logic. If every employee reports to one other employee, and no employee reports to zero employees, then that is what i must accomodate for, even if it means it is logically flawed/poorly designed. This db will not grant assignment privileges based on organizational heirarchy, and while that may be obviously flawed, it adheres to the logic of the excel file, and thus the class assignment. In other words, training modules can only be assigned by each employees direct supervisor. It will not accomodate skip level assigning.

Comment: "their logic. If every employee reports to one other employee, and no employee reports to zero employees, then that is what i must accomodate for, even if it means it is logically flawed/poorly designed" I wish it were that simple.  Within the context of your assignment you can't change it, so be it, but in the real world you have to push back on things like that or you're left with carnage.

Comment: i dont mean to be argumentative, but i really just think i have the logic correct here as far as the excel file is concerned. and while i agree that in a traditional db your method would be correct. im not being asked to build a working system, or even a logically sound system. Just one that strictly follows the data i was given.

Comment: "in the real world you have to push back on things like that or you're left with carnage." Great quote. And I'm glad that we agree.

Comment: Illustration of carnage here: https://dbfiddle.uk/MobClSa7.  The current issues with your diagram: You have the supervisor migrated to `FILLED_POSN` but it is not part of the primary key of `POSITION`. You may also notice that the entity `Supervisor` is superfluous - an `Employee` is a supervisor if they are listed on the `Position`.  Check  if a dept can exist across locations. Also, you only need a single line to represent the relationship, I recommend reading this to better understand the use of notation: http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf

Comment: Just to be clear, the `President` reports to someone?...if so who?

Comment: @J.D. The President reports to the Dir. Planning & Ops (and only them), and the Dir. Planning & Ops reports to the President, as well as 10 other individuals.

Comment: @bbaird  1) "You have the supervisor migrated to FILLED_POSN but it is not part of the primary key of POSITION"
Assumption: Recommends making POSITION(SupEMPLID) part of the primary key.
Response: I disagree because if I made SupEMPLID part of the PK, then that would allow an infinite number of supervisors to oversee each unique instance of POSITION (aka each unique combination of DeptID and JobCode). Excluding SupEMPLID from the PK was a conscious decision I made to ensure that one and only one supervisor can be assigned to each unique instance of POSITION.

Comment: @bbaird 2) "You may also notice that the entity Supervisor is superfluous - an Employee is a supervisor if they are listed on the Position."
Response: Ok I think…. Yes you are right on this one. I feel like there is a benefit to not letting SupEMPLID exist on its own in a separate entity. By requiring that SupEMPLID either be attached to the position it oversees (DeptID, JobCode), or not exist at all, then that creates a dependency between objects, and ensures one wont exist without the other. I like it.

Comment: @bbaird 3) "Check if a dept can exist across locations"
Response: Ahhh should LocationID also be a FK, or maybe even PK in POSITION and FILLED_POSN?
4) "Also, you only need a single line to represent the relationship."
Response: Could you please specify where exactly? TBH I havent fully scrutinized the cardinality and participation of all the relationships yet. Lucidchart is just stupid and defaults to one to many. i also dont fully think things through at times.